# wrong encoding for "?" character in Rest api

Tags: spring-boot, encode, spring-rest

I build a Rest API with Spring boot and when I pass a query with "?" character to test the get method with the query parameter the "?" character is not encoded.

Here you can find my spring controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/response/{query}", method =     RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
public  QueryRep getResponse(@PathVariable("query") String query)
{
     QueryRep test=new QueryRep();
     System.out.println(query);
// code !!
return test;
}
```

if I test for example: what is my name? I get the following url:
http://localhost:8080/response/what%20is%20my%20name? and I get in my console the string "what is my name" (without the "?" character).
As you can see the "?" character is not encoded as UTF-8 %3F while maven (pom.xml) and the IDE(STS) are configured to use UTF-8. I am using Tomcat as a web server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generic URI consists of the following:

**scheme:[//[user:password@]host[:port]][/]path[?query][#fragment]**

Notice the `?query` portion of the URI definition (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier)

So the ? is a reserved token that marks the end of the path and the beginning of the query string.  If you want to have a question mark character within your path you will have to encode it yourself with the %3F, such as:

http://localhost:8080/response/what%20is%20my%20name%3F

Then, if you further need a query string you can do so:

http://localhost:8080/response/what%20is%20my%20name%3F?myquery=stuff

Comment: if '?' is a valid caracter in URI so why I can't get it in my query I just get the question without '?' , thanks.